# Getting related items for a chosen item in mysql

Tags: mysql

Long time listener, first time caller. 
I've been researching this problem for a couple hours now, and have been unable to find an answer to my specific problem.

I have three tables in the database related to products:

- tbl_item (with `item_id`, `item_name`, etc...) -- basic item table
- tbl_item_term (with `term_id` and `term_name`) -- descriptive terms
- tbl_item_term_map (with `item_id` and `term_id`) -- assigns terms to items

Each item has multiple terms associated with them. What I'm trying to do is display all items related to the item being viewed, based on their terms.

For example:

```
item1 has term1, term2, term3 assigned to it<br>
item2 has term2, term4, term6 assigned to it<br>
item3 has term4, term5, term6 assigned to it
```

On each item page, I would like to show the related products. In this case, item3 would display item2 as a related product since it shares term4.

I've found a number of helpful answers to the *left-joining-three-tables* question, but nothing that fits this particular situation. Thanks in advance!

Chris

**EDIT**

Here is the code snip provided by Sajuna, modified to reflect my table/field names:

```
SELECT ti.item_name FROM tbl_item ti  
INNER JOIN tbl_item_term_map ttm on ttm.item_id = ti.item_id
INNER JOIN tbl_item_term tt on tt.term_id = ttm.term_id
WHERE tt.term_id IN (

    SELECT tt.term_name FROM tbl_item ti 
    INNER JOIN tbl_item_term_map ttm on ttm.item_id = ti.item_id
    INNER JOIN tbl_item_term tt on tt.term_id = ttm.term_id
    WHERE ti.item_id = 2536;

 );
```

When I run just the nested query, it returns the five fields that are assigned to the ID, as expected. But when I run the entire thing, I get an error (#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9 ). Is this what is meant by "not for production"?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you posted your table structures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its not for production you can use this.

```
SELECT tbl_item.id FROM tbl_item ti  
INNER JOIN tbl_item_term_map ttm on ttm.tbl_item_id = ti.id
INNER JOIN tbl_item_term tt on tt.id = ttm.tbl_item_term_id
WHERE tt.terms IN (

    SELECT tt.terms FROM tbl_item ti 
    INNER JOIN tbl_item_term_map ttm on ttm.tbl_item_id = ti.id
    INNER JOIN tbl_item_term tt on tt.id = ttm.tbl_item_term_id
    WHERE ti.id = 111;

 );
```

Comment: Thanks for code bit, but what do you mean by "not for production"? I plan on putting this on the website once it's ready, so I do need some code that I can use that way.

Comment: No what i meant was, if it was me i would do the first fetch to get the related terms for an item then store it in an array then do the second fetch to fetch the related items based on that array. Make sure your tables are properly indexed as well.