# Finding unique values from array across three tables

Tags: mysql

I have three tables in the database related to products:

```
tbl_item -- basic item table
---------
item_id |   item_name

tbl_item_term -- descriptive terms
--------------
term_id |   term_name

tbl_item_term_map -- assigns terms to items
-----------------
item_id |   term_id
```

Thanks to [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19340723/getting-related-items-for-a-chosen-item-in-mysql), I can select all of the items that are related to a particular item by term, by doing two queries.

One to collect the terms for an item (in this example item_id 2736):

```
SELECT
  tt.term_id
FROM tbl_item ti
  INNER JOIN tbl_item_term_map ttm
    on ttm.item_id = ti.item_id
  INNER JOIN tbl_item_term tt
    on tt.term_id = ttm.term_id
WHERE ti.item_id = 2736
```

I then parse the results into an array, so after a bit of php code, I'm left with:

```
$array = (1,7,12,20)
```

Then I take this array and plug it into my website like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  item_name
FROM tbl_item ti
  INNER JOIN tbl_item_term_map ttm
    on ttm.item_id = ti.item_id
  INNER JOIN tbl_item_term tt
    on tt.term_id = ttm.term_id
WHERE tt.term_id IN($array)
```

Which returns every related item with terms of `1,7,12,20`.

What I now want is to return items that have more than one term in common. For example,

```
related item1 has terms 1,2,3
related item2 has terms 1,7,9
related item3 has terms 7,8,9
```

Ideally, my new query would return just item2, since it has terms 1 and 7 in common. Any ideas?

Chris

**EDIT**

To put it another way, say I have this query:

```
SELECT ti.item_id 
FROM tbl_item ti
JOIN tbl_item_term_map ttm on ttm.item_id = ti.item_id
JOIN tbl_item_term tt on tt.term_id = ttm.term_id
WHERE tt.term_id = 1
UNION
SELECT ti.item_id 
FROM tbl_item ti
JOIN tbl_item_term_map ttm on ttm.item_id = ti.item_id
JOIN tbl_item_term tt on tt.term_id = ttm.term_id
WHERE tt.term_id = 7
```

The first query on its own provides 100 results and the second query provides 50 results, and when combined with `UNION`, the total is 120 unique IDs. It's that missing 30 duplicate IDs that I'm trying to extract. How can I get just the duplicates from the two queries?

Comment: can you post some sample data

Comment: What kind of sample data would you like to see? What would be the most helpful?

Comment: well i mean to say post some sample data of tables. some entries for each table. Always keep this thing in mind a good question contains 4 things. Clear defined problem, sample data , whatyouhave tried and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get those with more than on term then maybe something like this for your 2nd query:-

```
SELECT item_name, COUNT(tt.term_id) AS term_id_count, GROUP_CONCAT(tt.term_id)
FROM tbl_item ti
INNER JOIN tbl_item_term_map ttm ON ttm.item_id = ti.item_id
INNER JOIN tbl_item_term tt ON tt.term_id = ttm.term_id
WHERE tt.term_id IN($array)
GROUP BY item_name
HAVING term_id_count >= 2
```

You could maybe merge your 2 queries together like this:-

```
SELECT item_name, COUNT(tt.term_id) AS term_id_count, GROUP_CONCAT(tt.term_id)
FROM tbl_item ti
INNER JOIN tbl_item_term_map ttm ON ttm.item_id = ti.item_id
INNER JOIN tbl_item_term tt ON tt.term_id = ttm.term_id
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT tt.term_id
    FROM tbl_item ti
    INNER JOIN tbl_item_term_map ttm ON ttm.item_id = ti.item_id
    INNER JOIN tbl_item_term tt ON tt.term_id = ttm.term_id
    WHERE ti.item_id = 2736
) Sub1
ON tt.term_id = Sub1.term_id
GROUP BY item_name
HAVING term_id_count >= 2
```

If you just want the basic ones that are on all the subselects then:-

```
SELECT Sub1.item_id
FROM
(
    SELECT ti.item_id 
    FROM tbl_item ti
    JOIN tbl_item_term_map ttm on ttm.item_id = ti.item_id
    JOIN tbl_item_term tt on tt.term_id = ttm.term_id
    WHERE tt.term_id = 1
) Sub1
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT ti.item_id 
    FROM tbl_item ti
    JOIN tbl_item_term_map ttm on ttm.item_id = ti.item_id
    JOIN tbl_item_term tt on tt.term_id = ttm.term_id
    WHERE tt.term_id = 7
) sub2
ON Sub1.item_id = Sub2.item_id
```

Although using COUNT and HAVING should be quicker.

Comment: Thanks, but that only gives me results that have more than 2 terms associated with them, which isn't quite what I need. I've edited my original post to try to better explain my problem.

Comment: Not sure I get what the issue is. My first suggestion will bring back those where there are 2 terms associated with them (change the 2 to whatever is the max number of matching values), but that seems to be what you require from your edited answer. Could you post some sample data and sample results?